# Setting multiple labels one by one on button click for each

Tags: arrays, button, javafx, label

I have 9 labels and 1 button in my javaFx file. I want to set labels one by one after clicking the button for each time.how do i do that?
[image: this is the GUI]

When I press the button for first time "Number 1" label should change, when i press button for second time "Number 2" label should change and like that i want to change all labels

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private Label lblone;
@FXML
private Label lbltwo;
@FXML
private Label lblthree;
@FXML
private Label lblfour;
@FXML
private Label lblfive;
@FXML
private Label lblsix;
@FXML
private Label lblseven;
@FXML
private Label lbleight;
@FXML
private Label lblnine;



static int number = 0;
static List<Integer> revealed_no = new ArrayList<>(9);

public void randomNo(){
    number = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*((9-1)+1));
}

public void randomlist(){
    int i = 1;
    while ( !(revealed_no.contains(number)) && (i <= 9)){
        randomNo();
        revealed_no.add(number);
        i++;
    }
    
}}
```

This is my code in the Contoller.

Comment: add all label names in a string array and keep current Index every time you click show label increase index; BTW https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try this

```
public class App1 extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Greetings");  //creates title

    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    Button btn = new Button("ClicK");
    vBox.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 600, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();

    btn.setOnAction(event ->{
        Label label = new Label("Some Text");
        vBox.getChildren().add(label);
    });

}
}
```

Comment: as unclear as the question is, it has one detail that this answer completely ignores _clicking the button 9 times, it finish setting labels_ - please stop posting random code snippets, they don't help anybody!